# Java: what happens when a new Thread is started from a synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

First question here: it is a very short yet fundamental thing in Java that I don't know...

In the following case, is the `run()` method somehow executed with the lock that `somemethod()` did acquire?

```
public synchronized void somemethod() {
    Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable() {
       void run() {
           ...          <-- is a lock held here ?
       }
    }
    t.start();
    ... 
    (lengthy stuff performed here, keeping the lock held)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. `run()` starts in its own context, synchronization-wise. It doesn't hold any locks. If it did, you would either have a deadlock or it would violate the specs that state that only one thread may hold the lock on an object at any given time.

If `run()` was to call `somemethod()` again on the same object, it would have to wait for the `somemethod()` call that created it to complete first.

Answer (score 5):

No, only the original thread has the lock (because only one thread can hold a lock actually).

Comment: @ammoQ: ok great, +1 to you and Xr.  I validated Xr answer because he needs points :)   That said now I've got another question, related but different (and I've seen it's better to open a new question here)

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the new thread starts running in parallel to the synchronized method.

someMethod() still holds its own lock which only prevents this method from being invoked simultaneously against this instance of the object.

The thread does not inherit the lock, and will only be inhibited by the lock if the thread tries to call someMethod() against the object which created it if someMethod() is currently executing for that object.